# JavaScript Libraries with Visualforce

Tags: javascript

Please tell me that how i will run this below code...

```
<apex:page >

<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}"/>

<html>

<head>

  <script>

    jQuery.noConflict();

   jQuery(document).ready(function() {   

        jQuery("a").click(function() {

          alert("Hello world, part 2!");

        });

    });
  </script>

</head>
...

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and it looks correct.

It seems that you have issues with including script file.You can either download Jquery  JS file from [JQuery CDN](https://code.jquery.com/) and then add it in static resource with name jquery.

or you can directly provide link as well but it is not recommended.

```
<apex:includeScript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"/>
```

Comment: How i will define or save static resource for above code

Comment: Save this [Jquery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js) file. Add in static resource with name jquery and you are done.

Comment: Is there any jquery file online, i have to use for example

Comment: see my updated answer.

Comment: You should put the version in the file name. I also recommend reading up on IIFE.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Updated.Also looking for IIFE. Kind of aware of this standard approach but didn't know there is actually a term for it.Thanks.But not sure how it is relevant here.Can you put some light?

Comment: Check out [Mark Daiglesh](http://markdalgleish.com/presentations/gettingclosure/), his explanation is great. It's relevant here imo because it's much better practice to use it when actually implementing js libraries (esp jQuery), which seems part of OP. It also no longer matters who's already defined `$`, and you don't have to bother with `noConflict`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson That's really cool.It is always nice to see your comments.They always push me for better.Thanks.Keep up the good work.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. It's been good to see your content on here too. You use the platform well. Keep it up!